# Check if string ends with something using regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to check if a haystack ends with a needle containing some text that changes.

Here's what I tried and is showing "sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat" error:

```
import re

string = 'stuff ... </div> <img src="..." title"SOME_TEXT_THAT_CHANGES">'

pattern = r'/<\/div> <img src="..." title"(*.)">$/'

prog = re.compile(pattern)
result = prog.match(string)

print result
```

Comment: It's supposed to be `.*`.

Comment: I would guess, it should probably be `[^"]*`, to avoid matching something like `</div> <img src="..." title"SOME_TEXT_THAT_CHANGES" and some "other nonsense">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you regex to:

```
r'<\/div> <img src="[.]{3}" title"(.*)">$'
```

1. `.`  has a special meaning in regex, so you should use a character class or escape it using `\`.
2. No need to enclose regex between `/ /` in Python.
3. `*.` should be `.*`.
4. `re.match` matches only at the start of the string, so better use `re.search`.( [`re.search()` vs `re.match()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#search-vs-match))

**Demo:**

```
>>> pattern = r'<\/div> <img src="[.]{3}" title"(.*)">$'
>>> prog = re.compile(pattern)
>>> prog.search(string)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb5dcf920>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how it should be:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = 'stuff ... </div> <img src="..." title"SOME_TEXT_THAT_CHANGES">'
>>> pattern = r'</div> <img src="..." title"(.*)">$'
>>> prog = re.compile(pattern)
>>> result = prog.search(string)
>>> result
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0188A3A0>
>>> print result.group(1)
SOME_TEXT_THAT_CHANGES
>>>
```

Now let me go over the changes I made:

1. The pattern needed to have `*.` changed to `.*` (this is what caused the error).
2. You need to use `re.search` here, which searches for a pattern in a string, instead of `re.match`, which looks for an exact match.
3. You don't need the `/`'s at the start and end of Python Regexes.
4. `/` does not need to be escaped in `</div>`